# Receive data from web server

Tags: connection, webserver, client, server

I have a problem in a program that implements a simple web server.

When I send HTTP request to the webserver, the webserver sends HTTP code to client, but I want to receive => I have error  "Connection is reset!)

```java
clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
                new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()), "UTF-8")
);
out.write(OUTPUT_HEADERS+"GET /"+"home.html" + " HTTP/1.1\nHost:"+clientSocket.getLocalAddress() +"\nUser-agent: Mozilla/5.0\nAccept-language: fa");
out.flush();

System.out.println(" waiting...");

InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
while (br.ready()) {                
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
}
```

Comment: What does `OUTPUT_HEADERS` contain?

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTTP 1.1 spec:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/rfc2616bis/draft-lafon-rfc2616bis-03.html#request

The request and request headers needs to be terminated with CR/LF.

i.e. Change:

```java
out.write(OUTPUT_HEADERS+"GET /"+"home.html" + " HTTP/1.1\nHost:"+clientSocket.getLocalAddress() +"\nUser-agent: Mozilla/5.0\nAccept-language: fa");
out.flush();
```

to

```java
out.write(OUTPUT_HEADERS+"GET /"+"home.html" + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:"+clientSocket.getLocalAddress() +"\r\nUser-agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\nAccept-language: fa\r\n");
out.write("\r\n");
out.flush();
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If the answer is what you need you can 'accept' it.